# Flutter not showing rendered shimmer, but waits for future builder to have data before showing

Tags: flutter

I have a following piece of code:

```
...
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: tabController,
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder(
                future: customerController.getAllCustomers(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<List<CustomerModel>> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    print('showing real data: ${timer.elapsedMilliseconds}ms');
                    return AllCustomerView(
                      customerList: snapshot.data!,
                      setState: setState,
                    );
                  } else {
                    print('shimmer: ${timer.elapsedMilliseconds}ms');
                    return Shimmer.fromColors(
                      baseColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
                      highlightColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                      enabled: true,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        key: new PageStorageKey('customerList'),
                        itemCount: 20,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8),
                            child: ListWidget(
                              isSaved: false,
                              isShowingLoader: true,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                }),
...
```

and debug Console shows the timings I made using Stopwatch (see "print" calls in the code)

```
I/flutter (25917): initState: 3ms
I/flutter (25917): before setState: 6ms
I/flutter (25917): after setState: 7ms
I/flutter (25917): initState END: 10ms
I/flutter (25917): build finished: 44ms
I/flutter (25917): shimmer: 220ms
I/flutter (25917): getAllCustomers timer1: 1551ms
I/flutter (25917): getAllCustomers timer2: 26ms
I/flutter (25917): getAllCustomers timer3: 41ms
I/flutter (25917): showing real data: 11026ms
```

The problem is, I never get to see the shimmer. The app hangs on the previous screen until after snapshot.hasData is true in the FutureBuilder. Then I see the complete pupulated list (AllCustomerView).

It seems the flutter prioritizes the getAllCustomers call, instead of UI rendering the page.

Any Ideas what I might be doing wrong?